# Shiny app can't access data if runApp is run from a .Rprofile

Tags: r, shiny, initialization, rprofile

I built a Shiny app that makes use of a list variable (for label customization) that is created from an excel file. The name of this variable is `refvar`

`refvar` is created into `shinyServer()` in server.R and is used to build UI elements that are sent to ui.R. `refvar` is also used by `load.data()`. 
`load.data()` is defined into global.R and used into `shinyServer()`.

The odd thing is that if I run the app manually ("Run App" button in RStudio or runApp() from RStudio console) it works, while if I put `shiny::runApp()` in a .Rprofile file, to start the app as soon I open my RStudio project, I get the error "ERROR: object 'refvars' not found" in the browser.

Here's the (supposedly) relevant code

.Rprofile

```r
    shiny::runApp()
```

server.R

```r
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

        refvars <- read_excel('Labels.xlsx') %>% dplyr::select(1:2) %>% set_colnames(c('Var', 'Label')) %>% mutate_all(str_squish) %>% spread(Var, Label) %>% as.list


        Data <- load.data()

        output$UI.report.sel.text <- renderUI({helpText(refvars$report.sel.text)})
        output$UI.daterange.sel.text <- renderUI({helpText(refvars$daterange.sel.text)})


        #[...]
    })
```

global.R

```r
load.data <- function() {

    tryCatch(read_excel("Report_data.xlsx"), error = function(e) file.choose()) %>%
        rename(!!c(
            Anno = refvars$year,
            Mese = refvars$month,
            Indagine = refvars$report,
            Reparto = refvars$context,
            Note = refvars$notes,
            Problemi = refvars$problems,
            Sforamenti = refvars$non.compliance,
            Protocollo = refvars$id
        )) %>%
        mutate(
            Data = ymd(paste(Anno, Mese, '1', sep = '-'))
        )
}
```

UPDATE:

I made some experiments putting `refvar` in global.R. The app now starts well from the .Rprofile but some things are broken. For example where there should be a ggplot I get "ERROR: object 'title' not found", but actually I'm not using any `title` object.
I tried to inspect the status of the data I passed to ggplot via capture.output(str(Data)) and outputting it to ui.R via a uiOutput directive. The error became that it could find function `str()` and `capture.output()`; util package wasn't loaded!

So I suppose that the problem is that runApp() from .Rprofile run just too early. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was totally in the fact that default packages aren't still loaded when running .Rprofile.

So instead I had to redefine the .First.sys function adding my runApp code there:

.Rprofile

```r
pkg.require <- function(pkgs, load = T){
    installed <- utils::installed.packages()

    not.installed <- c()

    for (pkg in pkgs) {
        if (!(pkg %in% installed)) not.installed <- c(not.installed, pkg)
    }

    if (length(not.installed) > 0) utils::install.packages(not.installed)

    if (load) for (pkg in pkgs) library(pkg, character.only = TRUE)
}


.First.sys <- function () 
{
    for (pkg in getOption("defaultPackages")) {
        res <- require(pkg, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE, 
            character.only = TRUE)
        if (!res) 
            warning(gettextf("package %s in options(\"defaultPackages\") was not found", 
                sQuote(pkg)), call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
    }

    pkg.require(c('shiny'))

    shiny::runApp(launch.browser = T)
}
```